# Strange length and content of a char array based on another one in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a char array filled with letters and blanks (maximum length of 100) and I want to create another char array with the same length. This new array should contain a blank at a certain positions, if there's a blank in the original array, and a '#' if there's a letter. 
I need this for a hangman game in c and solved it this way:

```
//the original array is in a structure (with other char arrays)
//struct entry{
//char expression[100];
//....
//};

//which an array of called dictionary is created and filled later (this works)



//now the part where it somehow fails:

//figure out the length of the string in the first char array
int oldlength = strlen(dictionary[index].expression);

//create the new array (same length) and set its memory to 0 (doesn't actually matter)
char newexp[oldlength];
memset(newexp, 0, oldlength * sizeof(char));

//fill this new array as described
for(int i = 0; i < oldlength; i++)
{
    if(dictionary[index].expression[i] == ' ')
    {
        newexp[i] = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        newexp[i] = '#';
    }
}
```

Now I thought that this new array would work just the way i wanted it to. It sometimes does and my hangman game works completley fine in this cases. But sometimes it seems to make the new array longer than the old one and add weird characters (or maybe it's just the weird output of empty space (?)).

Now my way of testing this was:

```
printf("Expression in struct: %s\n", dictionary[index].expression);
printf("Length of expression in struct: %d\n", oldlength);
printf("Expression afterwards in new array: %s\n", newexp);
printf("Length of expression in new array: %d\n", strlen(newexp)); //I know, int != size_t
```

Now sometimes the game works and the output is something like :

```
Expression in struct: wonderful
Length of expression in struct: 9
Expression afterwards in new array: #########     //9x '#'
Length of expression in new array: 9
```

Note: The "//9x '#'" isnt in the output, I just counted them for faster understanding (same in the next examples)

But sometimes it give out stuff like this (actual, german example):

```
Expression in struct: glaesarn
Length of expression in struct: 8
æ@pression afterwards in new array: ########     //yes, 8x '#'
Length of expression in new array: 11
```

In this example I also give out the second array another time later and it says:

```
æ@######     //6x '#' ?
```

Tried it a few time... sometimes there's these two letters added at the beginning.. sometimes it's some other stuff at the end:

```
//another example

Expression in struct: Moebelrolle
Length of expression in struct: 11
æ@pression afterwards in new array: ######### ░h=v        i=væÚ7v     //9x '#' ?
Length of expression in new array: 27

//and later the arrays gives out
æ@######### ░h=v        i=væÚ7v     //9x '#'?
```

I don't understand how these two arrays can suddenly have such a different length (there's no other simultaneous access to it) and I thought this code to be relatively simple.
It also kinda boggles my mind how the output of "Expression afterwards" becomes "æ@pression afterwards"... how is this even possible ?

Comment: This line `char newexp[oldlength];` does not allocate enough space for the null byte after the string.  Whether that's the only problem is unclear; I spotted it first.  The code shown does not forcibly null-terminate `newexp`, which is a problem. Also, if you return the `newexp` from the function containing the code shown, you have problems.  You can't return a (useful) pointer to local storage in the function.  Either pass the `newexp` array to the function (with a suitable maximum size, like 101 bytes), or have the function dynamically allocate the memory (`malloc()` et al) and return that.

Comment: In my view, the `memset()` is pointless; you're about to overwrite every character that it zeroes with either a blank or a hash (`#`) mark.

Comment: even if it wasn't pointless, `{}` should be used instead, to reduce the possibility of memset length errors

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As you said it was due to not null-terminating `newexp`. Could you explain what exactly is happening in this case ? Like what kind of affect does the not null-terminated char array have ? Why can it get bigger ? And why does this only happen sometimes ?

I know, that I can't return a pointer to the local storage in the function, in my case I don't need to. And you're right, 'memset()' is pointless.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: At one level, I can't explain because you've invoked undefined behaviour by reading outside the bounds of the array.  At another, it's somewhat explicable.  Because the string is not null terminated, functions such as `printf()` with the `%s` conversion specification will read from the start up until it first encounters a null byte.  Since you didn't put a null byte in the array, you can't tell where it is going to find a null byte (and neither can I).  But it will keep going until it finds one.  Fortunately, small positive integers provide zero bytes.

Comment: As to 'why sometimes', it depends on what the system does.  For example, it might round the size of the array `newexp` up to an even byte boundary (or a multiple of 4 or even 8 bytes) to ensure alignment of other VLAs, in which case you'd sometimes have some space that's allocated but you're not allowed to use — that might prevent damage.  For other sizes, you get less buffer space, even no buffer space.  I don't know that this is what happens, but it or something like it could be a factor.  Undefined behaviour is bad precisely because you can't reason about it — the behaviour is undefined!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's exactly the explanation i was hoping for. I still wonder how this could corrupt the output of `printf("Expression afterwards in new array:...);` though. Shouldn't it still give out the (predefined) string correctly till I start reading out of bounds ? Meaning I would only have strange output **after** giving out the description and defined part of the array. Or could I read in a character which defines the start of a line ? Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need to change:

```
char newexp[oldlength];
```

To:

```
char newexp[oldlength + 1];
```

And put null terminator `\0` to the end of `newexp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine now all the time.
Could you explain what exactly happens, when I don't use your solution and why it only fails sometimes ?

Comment: @fsalad I see, that the explanation of @JonathanLeffler is great. In a few words, `printf` function needs to know where printed string ends. So it tries to find first null byte lying after the beginning of the printed string and suppose that it's the end. In your case, there's no null byte putting manually to mark the end, so `printf` can find this byte anywhere after the real string end.

Comment: @fsalad  You don't know in advance how memory lying after the real string end looks. Maybe there's a null byte immediately after the real string end, maybe this byte lies much more further, nobody knows. That's why your string sometimes is printed correctly, but sometimes contains strange symbols in the end.